# Windows and BlackBerry device for learning penetration testing

Tags: blackberry, windows-phone

I want to buy a Windows Phone 8 and a Blackberry (BB) device for practicing penetration testing of mobile applications (of course, Windows and BB apps).

`I am asking for appropriate devices. I don't want alternative of emulators please`  I have tried emulators concept but it does not suit well as is the case with Android devices. It is cumbersome to set up Windows emulators as my laptop does not meet the specifications.

Can anyone suggest a good Windows as well as Blackberry phone that best suits for pentest of mobile apps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Windows Phone 8 I would buy a Nokia Lumia 520. It's cheap, I guess it can do anything that other WP phones can do. Why buy something expensive? Maybe if you need more memory or storage?

For Blackberry, which OS? There are many versions, each with its own problems I guess.

Comment: Thank you @SPRBRN. This will help me in some way. 
I will get back to you for BlackBerry OS. 

Btw, is it possible to jailbreak Windows devices as similar to rooting android devices ?

Comment: Apparently you can jailbreak WP8, but read the warning as you don't know what kind of malware you install doing this! http://windowsphonehub.in/tutorials/dev-unlock-chinese-hack-tool-developer-unlock-windows-phone-sideload-10-xaps/ You can just google stuff like this! I have no Windows Phone, so no experience doing this.

Comment: hey, I bought the Lumia 520. 
And most apparently, the OS version of BB would be 10. Can you suggest some BB phone that is good for pentest purpose. TIA.

Comment: I think the BB Z10 is the cheapest on the market right now. Maybe second hand?

Comment: Yeah I will look for the second hand device. 
Though some of them have closed this question stating "off-topic" but then too I appreciate your help @SPRBRN. 
Thanks a lot mate.